# Magento 2 ReCaptcha Module Intermittently Fails for New Account Creation

Tags: knockout.js, magento2, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

In our Magento 2 system, we've integrated the Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi module to handle reCAPTCHA during customer account creation. However, we are encountering an issue where some customers receive the error message: "Something went wrong with reCAPTCHA. Please contact the store owner."

The challenge is that this error seems intermittent and cannot be consistently reproduced. It occurs for some users in various scenarios, including in incognito mode. Interestingly, when I remotely connected to a PC experiencing this issue, I noticed that the getTemplate function within the recaptcha.phtml template file (vendor/magento/module-re-captcha-frontend-ui/view/frontend/templates/recaptcha.phtml) was not functioning as expected.

To assist in diagnosing this issue, I'd like to share the relevant code snippets from the recaptcha.phtml file. Specifically, I'd like to provide the code that defines the getTemplate function.

Could someone please help me identify the potential causes of this intermittent reCAPTCHA failure and provide guidance on how to fix it?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

The file : vendor/magento/module-re-captcha-frontend-ui/view/frontend/templates/recaptcha.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

/** @var $block \Magento\ReCaptchaUi\Block\ReCaptcha */
?>
<div
    class="field-recaptcha"
    id="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getRecaptchaId() ?>-container"
    data-bind="scope:'<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getRecaptchaId() ?>'"
>
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getRecaptchaId() ?>-container": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
    }
}
</script>
```

The getTemplate() would load the following html

vendor/magento/module-re-captcha-frontend-ui/view/frontend/web/template/reCaptcha.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
 -->

<div data-bind="{
    attr: {
        'id': getReCaptchaId() + '-wrapper'
    },
    'afterRender': renderReCaptcha()
}">
    <div class="g-recaptcha"></div>
    <!-- ko if: (!getIsInvisibleRecaptcha()) -->
    <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   value=""
                   class="required-captcha checkbox"
                   name="recaptcha-validate-"
                   data-validate="{required:true}"
                   tabindex="-1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

If the second template is not loading then the error message will happend.